# How to create columns dynamically from data in antd?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to create a reusable data table component using antd where columns create dynamically from data. How can I do that?

here is my code:

```
 const data= [
  {
    key: 1,
    name: 'Jack',
    email:'jack@gmail.com',
    address: 'Dhaka'
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    name: 'jon',
    email:'jon@gmail.com',
    address: 'Dhaka'
  }
];

const TableContainer = (props) => {
  const { columns, data, loading } = props;

  return <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data} loading={loading} />;
};

export default TableContainer;
```

Comment: If you need to decide it by `data`, then why you pass `columns` from `props` ? Then again, how can you decide the `title` you want for the relevant column, if you're trying to decide columns by the data ?

Comment: without passing columns, not show data in antd table, I want to reuseable component.

Comment: So just to be clear, you don't want to pass `columns` anymore from `props`, and you need completely create it from your `data` object inside the component ?

Comment: By the way, until you fetch data from backed or if you have an empty `data` object, then table won't show anything since it's the actual behavior of it. So you need to stop showing your table if you don't have any data right ?

Comment: yes. how can I do that?

Comment: Please check the answer and tell if any modification is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally render your table based on `data.length` as follows. If you have an empty array, then it won't show the table.

```
const TableContainer = (props) => {
  const { columns, data, loading } = props;

   return (
    <>{data?.length > 0 && <Table columns={columns} dataSource={data}  loading={loading} />}</>
  );
};
```